# SVG in HTML doesn't work

Tags: animation, svg, loader

See the code in [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbEGNr)

```
<svg version="1.1" id="wrapper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="273px" height="125.2px" viewBox="0 0 273 125.2" enable-background="new 0 0 273 125.2" xml:space="preserve">

<path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
    M2,65.7C49.2,3.8,29.8,2.1,27.4,2c-2.4-0.1-4.4,2.2-6.6,5.3c-10.2,14.8-10.4,40.3-8.7,45s4.6,15.3,11.7,16.5
    c5.5,0.9,10.8-2.9,14.3-7.4c3.5-4.4,6-9.7,10.2-13.4c4.2-3.7,11.1-5.4,15.4-1.7c-5-0.4-10.3-0.4-14.9,1.7s-8.2,7.1-7.3,12.1
    c1.1,5.9,8.5,9.2,14.2,7.3s9.5-7.6,10.8-13.5c0.6-3,0.5-6.5-1.7-8.5c-2.2-2-6.9-0.7-6.7,2.3c0.2,2.1,2.4,3.3,4.4,3.8
    c5.5,1.2,11.2-0.7,16.5-2.7c5.3-1.9,11-3.8,16.5-2.4c5.5,1.4,10,7.7,7.5,12.8c-0.6-7.2-7.3-13.4-14.5-13.3
    c-7.2,0.2-13.7,7.1-13,14.3s8.6,12.9,15.6,10.8c7.5-2.2,11-11.3,10-19.1c-1.8,3.2-1.5,13.5,0.8,16.3c2.3,2.8,6.5,4,9.9,2.8
    c4.4-1.5,6.9-12.1,9.5-16s6.5-7.9,11.1-7.2c5.2,0.8,7.6,6.8,9.1,11.9c0.3-6.2-5.6-12-11.8-11.6c-6.2,0.4-11.3,6.9-10.2,13.1
    c1.1,6.1,8.2,10.5,14.2,8.7c7.4-2.2,10.3-11.1,11.3-18.8c1.9-14.6,0.9-29.5-2.8-43.7c-3,16.8-3.3,34-0.9,50.9
    c0.8,5.7,2.6,12.3,7.8,14.8c5.8,2.8,12.9-1.2,16-6.8c3-5.6,3-12.4,2.8-18.8c-1.5,5.8-3.1,11.9-1.4,17.7c1.6,5.8,7.7,10.8,13.4,8.9
    c5-1.6,7.4-7.5,7.7-12.8s-0.9-10.6,0.1-15.8c-1.8,10.2-0.9,20.9,2.5,30.7c0.5-7.1,1.1-14.3,1.6-21.4c0.2-2.5,0.5-5.4,2.4-7
    c3.6-3.1,9.5,0.6,10.8,5.2c1.3,4.6-0.1,9.5,0,14.2c0.1,4,1.8,8.7,5.7,9.7c3.7,1,7.5-2,9.2-5.4c1.8-3.4,2.2-7.4,3.6-11
    c1.9-4.7,5.6-8.8,10.4-10.4s10.6-0.3,13.8,3.7s2.9,10.4-1.1,13.6c4.4-4.6,4.4-12.7,0.1-17.5s-12.2-5.5-17.5-1.9s-7.3,11.2-4.8,17.1
    c3.1,7.2,12.7,10.8,19.7,7.3c7-3.5,10.1-13.3,6.2-20.1c1.1,20,2.2,40,3.3,60c0.2,3.7,0,8.2-3.3,10c-4.1,2.3-8.9-2.1-10.7-6.5
    c-4.6-11-1.6-24.8,7.3-32.9c4.7-4.3,10.8-6.9,15.8-10.9c5-4,9.2-10.1,7.9-16.4"/>
<path fill="none" class="path2" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
    M177.7,20.2c-2.3-2.5-7-2.1-8.8,0.8c-1.8,2.9,0,7.3,3.3,8.2c2.3,0.6,4.9-0.4,6.2-2.4S179.3,22,177.7,20.2z"/>
```

It works perfectly fine . but when i try it myself . The Loading image appears but it does not animate .

Comment: Are you also using the css which is provided in that codepen?

Comment: you will have to insert the css in the same file as the svg or refer to the separate css file. please make sure you did that

Comment: i already did that , i put css in the same page as the svg and i tried to link the css but nothing happens

Comment: The snippet you posted is actually not complete. Take a good look at the html part in the codepen again.

Comment: do you mean the closing tag of svg ?

Comment: Indeed you need to make sure all the code is copied from the codepen sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The included CSS will only work on some browsers.  Webkit-based browsers still require you to use the `-webkit-` prefix on CSS animation properties.  Ie.

```
-webkit-animation
@-webkit-keyframes
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

If you add the '-webkit-' variants of those CSS rules, everything should work.  See below.

The reason it works on codepen is because it seems codepen includes a script that corrects for those browser differences.

```css
body{
  background:#fd0;
}
#wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  90% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  90% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  -webkit-animation: dash2 5s linear  infinite;
  animation: dash2 5s linear  infinite;
}

@keyframes dash2 {
  60% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash2 {
  60% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="wrapper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="273px" height="125.2px" viewBox="0 0 273 125.2" enable-background="new 0 0 273 125.2" xml:space="preserve">

 <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
  M2,65.7C49.2,3.8,29.8,2.1,27.4,2c-2.4-0.1-4.4,2.2-6.6,5.3c-10.2,14.8-10.4,40.3-8.7,45s4.6,15.3,11.7,16.5
  c5.5,0.9,10.8-2.9,14.3-7.4c3.5-4.4,6-9.7,10.2-13.4c4.2-3.7,11.1-5.4,15.4-1.7c-5-0.4-10.3-0.4-14.9,1.7s-8.2,7.1-7.3,12.1
  c1.1,5.9,8.5,9.2,14.2,7.3s9.5-7.6,10.8-13.5c0.6-3,0.5-6.5-1.7-8.5c-2.2-2-6.9-0.7-6.7,2.3c0.2,2.1,2.4,3.3,4.4,3.8
  c5.5,1.2,11.2-0.7,16.5-2.7c5.3-1.9,11-3.8,16.5-2.4c5.5,1.4,10,7.7,7.5,12.8c-0.6-7.2-7.3-13.4-14.5-13.3
  c-7.2,0.2-13.7,7.1-13,14.3s8.6,12.9,15.6,10.8c7.5-2.2,11-11.3,10-19.1c-1.8,3.2-1.5,13.5,0.8,16.3c2.3,2.8,6.5,4,9.9,2.8
  c4.4-1.5,6.9-12.1,9.5-16s6.5-7.9,11.1-7.2c5.2,0.8,7.6,6.8,9.1,11.9c0.3-6.2-5.6-12-11.8-11.6c-6.2,0.4-11.3,6.9-10.2,13.1
  c1.1,6.1,8.2,10.5,14.2,8.7c7.4-2.2,10.3-11.1,11.3-18.8c1.9-14.6,0.9-29.5-2.8-43.7c-3,16.8-3.3,34-0.9,50.9
  c0.8,5.7,2.6,12.3,7.8,14.8c5.8,2.8,12.9-1.2,16-6.8c3-5.6,3-12.4,2.8-18.8c-1.5,5.8-3.1,11.9-1.4,17.7c1.6,5.8,7.7,10.8,13.4,8.9
  c5-1.6,7.4-7.5,7.7-12.8s-0.9-10.6,0.1-15.8c-1.8,10.2-0.9,20.9,2.5,30.7c0.5-7.1,1.1-14.3,1.6-21.4c0.2-2.5,0.5-5.4,2.4-7
  c3.6-3.1,9.5,0.6,10.8,5.2c1.3,4.6-0.1,9.5,0,14.2c0.1,4,1.8,8.7,5.7,9.7c3.7,1,7.5-2,9.2-5.4c1.8-3.4,2.2-7.4,3.6-11
  c1.9-4.7,5.6-8.8,10.4-10.4s10.6-0.3,13.8,3.7s2.9,10.4-1.1,13.6c4.4-4.6,4.4-12.7,0.1-17.5s-12.2-5.5-17.5-1.9s-7.3,11.2-4.8,17.1
  c3.1,7.2,12.7,10.8,19.7,7.3c7-3.5,10.1-13.3,6.2-20.1c1.1,20,2.2,40,3.3,60c0.2,3.7,0,8.2-3.3,10c-4.1,2.3-8.9-2.1-10.7-6.5
  c-4.6-11-1.6-24.8,7.3-32.9c4.7-4.3,10.8-6.9,15.8-10.9c5-4,9.2-10.1,7.9-16.4"/>
 <path fill="none" class="path2" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
  M177.7,20.2c-2.3-2.5-7-2.1-8.8,0.8c-1.8,2.9,0,7.3,3.3,8.2c2.3,0.6,4.9-0.4,6.2-2.4S179.3,22,177.7,20.2z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure why, but adding `<script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>` works. (a codepen  '-webkit-' polyfill, i guess)

Hope this helps.

```css
body{
  background:#fd0;
}
#wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  90% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.path2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash2 5s linear  infinite;
}

@keyframes dash2 {
  60% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="wrapper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="273px" height="125.2px" viewBox="0 0 273 125.2" enable-background="new 0 0 273 125.2" xml:space="preserve">

 <path class="path" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
  M2,65.7C49.2,3.8,29.8,2.1,27.4,2c-2.4-0.1-4.4,2.2-6.6,5.3c-10.2,14.8-10.4,40.3-8.7,45s4.6,15.3,11.7,16.5
  c5.5,0.9,10.8-2.9,14.3-7.4c3.5-4.4,6-9.7,10.2-13.4c4.2-3.7,11.1-5.4,15.4-1.7c-5-0.4-10.3-0.4-14.9,1.7s-8.2,7.1-7.3,12.1
  c1.1,5.9,8.5,9.2,14.2,7.3s9.5-7.6,10.8-13.5c0.6-3,0.5-6.5-1.7-8.5c-2.2-2-6.9-0.7-6.7,2.3c0.2,2.1,2.4,3.3,4.4,3.8
  c5.5,1.2,11.2-0.7,16.5-2.7c5.3-1.9,11-3.8,16.5-2.4c5.5,1.4,10,7.7,7.5,12.8c-0.6-7.2-7.3-13.4-14.5-13.3
  c-7.2,0.2-13.7,7.1-13,14.3s8.6,12.9,15.6,10.8c7.5-2.2,11-11.3,10-19.1c-1.8,3.2-1.5,13.5,0.8,16.3c2.3,2.8,6.5,4,9.9,2.8
  c4.4-1.5,6.9-12.1,9.5-16s6.5-7.9,11.1-7.2c5.2,0.8,7.6,6.8,9.1,11.9c0.3-6.2-5.6-12-11.8-11.6c-6.2,0.4-11.3,6.9-10.2,13.1
  c1.1,6.1,8.2,10.5,14.2,8.7c7.4-2.2,10.3-11.1,11.3-18.8c1.9-14.6,0.9-29.5-2.8-43.7c-3,16.8-3.3,34-0.9,50.9
  c0.8,5.7,2.6,12.3,7.8,14.8c5.8,2.8,12.9-1.2,16-6.8c3-5.6,3-12.4,2.8-18.8c-1.5,5.8-3.1,11.9-1.4,17.7c1.6,5.8,7.7,10.8,13.4,8.9
  c5-1.6,7.4-7.5,7.7-12.8s-0.9-10.6,0.1-15.8c-1.8,10.2-0.9,20.9,2.5,30.7c0.5-7.1,1.1-14.3,1.6-21.4c0.2-2.5,0.5-5.4,2.4-7
  c3.6-3.1,9.5,0.6,10.8,5.2c1.3,4.6-0.1,9.5,0,14.2c0.1,4,1.8,8.7,5.7,9.7c3.7,1,7.5-2,9.2-5.4c1.8-3.4,2.2-7.4,3.6-11
  c1.9-4.7,5.6-8.8,10.4-10.4s10.6-0.3,13.8,3.7s2.9,10.4-1.1,13.6c4.4-4.6,4.4-12.7,0.1-17.5s-12.2-5.5-17.5-1.9s-7.3,11.2-4.8,17.1
  c3.1,7.2,12.7,10.8,19.7,7.3c7-3.5,10.1-13.3,6.2-20.1c1.1,20,2.2,40,3.3,60c0.2,3.7,0,8.2-3.3,10c-4.1,2.3-8.9-2.1-10.7-6.5
  c-4.6-11-1.6-24.8,7.3-32.9c4.7-4.3,10.8-6.9,15.8-10.9c5-4,9.2-10.1,7.9-16.4"/>
 <path fill="none" class="path2" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
  M177.7,20.2c-2.3-2.5-7-2.1-8.8,0.8c-1.8,2.9,0,7.3,3.3,8.2c2.3,0.6,4.9-0.4,6.2-2.4S179.3,22,177.7,20.2z"/>
</svg>
```